# Intervals in which $f(x)$ is Strictly Increasing of Decreasing.

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

What are the Intervals in which the Function

$f(x)= \sin(3x) - \cos(3x)$  where $x$ belongs to the interval $(0,π)
$

is Increasing, Decreasing, Strictly Increasing , Strictly Decreasing.

Answer to this question can be found any where on the Internet but I want to know what is the methodology/algorithm used to solve this type of functions.

Comment: And didn't these answers you found on internet contain the methodology/algorithm?

Comment: that is what i couldn't understand. my teacher did differentiation to find out but the problem comes out with finding intervals and i cannot predict the sign of the f'(x).

Comment: This is just a standard exercise: you need to use derivatives. Alternatively, you can use prosthapheresis formulas to express that difference in a convenient way.

Comment: So the problem is that you cannot solve the inequality that derives from this problem? Start it and let us see where you fail to continue ;)

Comment: so i get tan3x= -1 and x= π/4 and 7π/12 now after that  with what i make intervals x or 3x?

Comment: to predict the sing of f'(x).

Comment: I've expanded that in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50690/discussion-between-pushkar-soni-and-harnak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of solving the inequality $$\cos(3x) + \sin(3x) > 0$$
This can be done via parametric formulas: $$\sin(3x) = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$ $$\cos(3x) = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$
where $t = \tan(\frac{3}{2}x)$.

An alternative way of solving this would be by setting $X= \cos(3x)$ and $Y = \sin(3x)$ and solving the resulting system: 
$$\begin{cases} 
X+Y > 0 \\
X^2+Y^2 = 1\end{cases}$$
This can be done in an agile way graphically.

EDIT: I'll use the second method to solve this. The solution to the previous is system is all the $(X,Y)$ on the unitary circumference that are over the line $Y=-X$.
We get that these are all the points on the circumference between an angle of $-\pi/4$ and $-\pi/4 + \pi=3\pi/4$.
This means that $-\frac{\pi}{4} + 2k\pi < 3x < \frac{3}{4}\pi + 2k\pi$ and, by dividing by $3$: $$-\frac{\pi}{12} +\frac{2}{3}k\pi < x < \frac{3}{12}\pi + \frac{2}{3}k\pi$$
In such intervals, the function is increasing, in the others it's decreasing.
(Now you just have to restrict to $(0,\pi)$ since you're interested in that interval)

Comment: thank you very much i understood everything.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

Notice that

$$\sin(3x)-\cos(3x)=\sqrt2\sin\left(3x-\frac\pi4\right)$$

Thus, we only need to check when $\sin\left(3x-\frac\pi4\right)$ is increasing, decreasing, etc.  Can you do that?

Comment: can you do that too please. i am little bit confused with predicting the sign of that.

Comment: @PushkarSoni Can you take the derivative?  After that, it is left to find the places where $\cos(3x-\pi/4)$ changes sign, right?

Comment: yes i did that but, now how to take care of the quadrants in which (3x-π/4) lies an predict the sign of the derivative.

Comment: @PushkarSoni Well, do you know when $\cos(x)$ changes sign?

Comment: yes i know that.

Comment: its negative in 2nd and 3rd quad.

Comment: @PushkarSoni So $\cos(z)$ changes signs between 1st and 2nd quad.  Then again between 3rd 4th quad.  What are these values of $z$?  So let $z=3x-\pi/4$.  Can you find $x$?

Answer (score 1):

To consider the variation of a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ the standard method is to consider the sign of the derivative (supposedly existing) $f':\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. If this function ($f'$) is continuous, you can simply solve for its zero locus - the points where its value is zero, from which you can deduce the intervals where the sign of the function ($f'$) stays unchanged, so we can take just a sample to know its sign there.